# Copy a linked list in c

Tags: c, list, linked-list

```
typedef struct slist *LInt;

typedef struct slist{

int value;
LInt prox;
}Node;

LInt clone2(LInt l){

LInt nova=NULL,aux2=NULL;
while(l){
    aux2=nova;
    nova=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nova->value=l->value;
    nova->prox=aux2;
    l=l->prox;
    }
return nova;
}
```

This function is supposed to copy a linked list, but this way, when I call the function to print it on screen, the list comes up reversed... Any help or tip? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your routine builds a reversed copy of the list. I do the same thing, except I have a last step of reversing the copy, as in: `novb=NULL;while(nova){LInt temp=nova; nova=nova->prox; temp->prox=novb; novb=temp;}`. Then `novb` has it in the original order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `nova->prox=aux2;` where `aux2` is the previous node....thus, you are actually pointing backwards in the linked list.

Pls look at these links for correct logic:

[Coding a function to copy a linked-list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082586/coding-a-function-to-copy-a-linked-list-in-c)

Adapted @templatetypedef's answer from [How do you copy a linked list into another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984071/how-do-you-copy-a-linked-list-into-another-list)

```
LInt Clone(LInt l) {
if (l == NULL) return NULL;

LInt result = (LInt)malloc(sizeof(Node));
result->value = l->value;
result->prox = Clone(l->next);
return result;
}
```

Comment: I posted two links, do they help?

Comment: sort of :) they are both in C++, not in C, but I think I can make it work! thank you for you help!

Comment: I adapted one of the answers posted there and updated the answer...hope it helps. BTW, I am not sure if `prox` and `aux` have some specific meaning. If you use `next` instead of `prox`, it might be easier to read. Just a suggestion.

Comment: thank you for your help! yes, prox means next in my language :)

Comment: awesome!! I was guessing that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
LInt clone2(LInt l){
    LInt ret=NULL;
    LInt nova, aux2 = NULL;
    while(l){
        nova=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if(!ret) ret = nova;
        if(aux2) aux2->prox = nova;
        nova->value=l->value;
        nova->prox = NULL;
        aux2 = nova;
        l=l->prox;
    }
    return ret;
}
```