# How to copy a linked list double sorted in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

i has defined a list using :

```
typedef struct st_list {
Node * by_name ;
Node * by_age;
} SortedList ;
```

After that I defined the node using :

```
typedef struct st_node {
char name [100];
unsigned int age;
struct st_node * suivant_nom ;
struct st_node * suivant_age ;
} Node ;
```

After that i defined a function to insert an element in this list :

```
void insert (SortedList* l , char* name , int age ){
     Node *N,*A,*tmp,*new;
     N=l->by_name;
     A=l->by_age;
     tmp=NULL;
     new= (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
     new->age=age;
     new->name=strcpy(new->name,name);
     if (N==NULL) {N=new;}
     while ((N!=NULL) & strcpy(name,N->name)<0){
          tmp=N;
          N=N->suivant_nom;}
     tmp->suivant_nom=new;
     new->suivant_nom=N;
    while ((N!=NULL) & strcpy(name,N->name)<0){
          tmp=N;
          N=N->suivant_nom;}
     tmp->suivant_age=new;
     new->suivant_age=N;}
```

After that i defined also a function with this prototype :

```
Node* copyNode(None* p) ;
```

Which copy a node and return a pointer to a copy of it .

What i want to do right now is to implement a function that make a copy of a list given as argument , it's prototype will be :

```
SortedList* duplicatelist( SortedList l) ;
```

This function will return  a pointer to the copy of the SortedList l ;
I know an Algorithm In C which copy a LinkedList , like [How do you copy a linked list into another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984071/how-do-you-copy-a-linked-list-into-another-list) , but there we can not use this method because the list is double sorted .
I tried to use an array and put all the elements of the list given in argument , and make a for loop such as that `tab[i]->suivant_age=tab[i+1]` but there again , we can implement the sorting by age .
I hope i was clear and i explaned well my problem ?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @OznOg I tried to use an array and put all the elements of the list given in argument , and make a for loop such as that tab[i]->suivant_age=tab[i+1] but there again , we can implement the sorting by age

Comment: The Pico style of indentation with the close brace hidden on the right is not a conventional C style.  Please use Allman (my choice) or 1TBS — see Wikipedia on [Indentation Styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   The problem is not in this function , the main reason why i am asking there is for the function duplicate function

Comment: OK; if the problem isn't in this code, why are you showing it to us?  Where is your code that does attempt to handle the copying of a complete list?  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) showing that code in particular.  I think you should be able to handle it by creating a second list structure, then iterating over one (it doesn't matter which) of the lists in the original, repeatedly inserting into the copy.

Comment: In the (revised) code, you have: `while ((N!=NULL) & strcpy(name,N->name)<0){` — Are you sure you should be using bitwise `&` rather than logical `&&`? — And are you sure you should be using `strcpy()` rather than `strcmp()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because if i didn't show it , some users may think that i'm so lazy and i'm asking for help from scratch

Comment: Well, there's an element of "you are asking for help from scratch" — you've not shown how you plan to handle the copy operation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i already said that i tried to  to use an array and put all the elements of the list given in argument , and make a for loop such as that tab[i]->suivant_age=tab[i+1] but there again , we can implement the sorting by age

Comment: That is a description of the code, not showing the actual code you've tried. It makes it difficult for us to know what you're doing. It isn't clear how you create the array you mention, for example. It also isn't clear that an array is necessary — but these things are easier to deal with if you supply the code for the copying that you've tried.  We can't fix what we can't see. You should not expect us to write your code for you, but we will (usually) help you fix an honest attempt to solve the problem if you identify the specific issues you're facing — an MCVE! ("No idea" isn't specific.)